# Difference between licensing terms of code-server vs. VS Code Server

Tags: licensing, code-server, visual-studio-code-server

I am trying to understand the licensing limitations if I want to bundle code-server with my cloud application.

As per the [docs](https://coder.com/docs/code-server/latest), Out of the box, `code-server` is simply **VS Code in the browser**

Since `code-server` uses open source code of `VS Code`, how does the licensing terms of `VS Code Server` affect usage of `code-server` in a commercial application? As per `VS Code Server` [FAQ](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/vscode-server) and [licensing terms](https://aka.ms/vscode-server-license) -

- hosting `VS Code Server` as a service is not allowed
- you may not provide the software as a stand-alone offering or combine it with any of your applications for others to use, or transfer the software or this agreement to any third party.

So, if I ship code-server [helm](https://coder.com/docs/code-server/latest/helm) charts with my commercial cloud application, will it be breaking VS Code Server's license terms?